# SICP Checking eval is a thunk?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, sicp, thunk

In Sec 4.2.2 of SICP,

```
(define (list-of-arg-values exps env)
  (if (no-operands? exps)
      '()
      (cons (actual-value (first-operand exps) env)
            (list-of-arg-values (rest-operands exps)
                                env))))
```

Calls

```
(define (actual-value exp env)
  (force-it (eval exp env)))
```

Calls

```
(define (force-it obj)
  (if (thunk? obj)
      (actual-value (thunk-exp obj) (thunk-env obj))
      obj))
```

As per the thunk structure

```
(define (delay-it exp env)
  (list 'thunk exp env))

(define (thunk? obj)
  (tagged-list? obj 'thunk))
```

If the first operand was a thunk , why does it check whether the eval is a thunk?

If the operand is a thunk it would be like "list `thunk` exp `env". but why is it testing if the eval is a thunk?

Can someone please explain how this part works together along with an example

Comment: When `eval` is lazy what `eval` is returning is always a `thunk`. When you need to force it it might not be enough to force only one level so it forces as long as the value is a `thunk`.  The second it isn't it is the actual forced value fully evaluated. Imagine the expression `(+ a b)` needs to evaluate `+`, `a`, `b` before it can actually apply so with lazy evaluation the expression won't actually be run until you force it and then it will evaluate at least 4 things (a and b might be stuff needs forcing too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented By Sylwester,

When eval is lazy what eval is returning is always a thunk. When you need to force it it might not be enough to force only one level so it forces as long as the value is a thunk. The second it isn't it is the actual forced value fully evaluated. Imagine the expression (+ a b) needs to evaluate +, a, b before it can actually apply so with lazy evaluation the expression won't actually be run until you force it and then it will evaluate at least 4 things (a and b might be stuff needs forcing too)

Answer (score -1):

The return value of the evaluation gets forced. An object can only be forced, if it is a chunk. So it is checked, if it is a chunk.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense to me and doesn't answer my question. Is eval the thunk or exp?

Comment: @user10206517 Neither. `eval` is used in an [application](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.5) (function call). The call of the procedure `eval` returns a value, which is passed to `force-it`. And therefor the return value of `eval` must be a thunk.